# How do I crate a virtual ftp user with preseted password using ftpasswd and bash

Tags: bash, password, ftp

Hello command line gurus, I've created an ftp user like this:

```
ftpasswd --passwd --name webftp --uid 33 --home /var/www --shell /bin/false
```

What I like to do is to create the same user with a preseted password using the `--stdin` option. If I use:

```
echo < passwd > | ftpasswd --stdin --passwd --name webftp --uid 33 --home /var/www --shell /bin/false
```

I got a message which told me that there the password is not set.

Does anyone see the mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you to use:

```
passwd="your_password"
echo $passwd | ftpasswd --stdin --passwd --name webftp --uid 33 --home /var/www --shell /bin/false
```

or

```
ftpasswd --stdin --passwd --name webftp --uid 33 --home /var/www --shell /bin/false < passwd.txt
```

where `passwd.txt` is a file that contain the password.

These because:

> [...] the `--stdin` option does **not** allow passwords to be passed to the script on the command line, but on stdin. This is done as a security measure: the standard Unix `ps` command can be used to show all the processes running on a system including their command line parameters. This means that any user could use `ps` to watch passwords given to `ftpasswd`, **if those passwords were to be passed on the command line**.

More about:

- http://pl.digipedia.org/man/doc/view/ftpasswd.8/
- http://www.proftpd.org/docs/utils/ftpasswd.html